# OpenGL SwapBuffers() latency on Windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, latency, framebuffer

I'm writing hardware decoding software that takes a stream of a Desktop over the network and displays it in an OpenGL window. I need the total stream latency to be as close to real time as possible. To measure the latency, I have a stopwatch running on the source Desktop and then use a camera to take a picture of the source and the application together. The end-to-end latency ends up being the difference in timer reading from the source to the application.

As of now, I have a end-to-end latency of around 83-100ms. And I'm fairly confident the latency from [Encoding > Network > Decoding > OpenGL's SwapBuffers() in the application] is taking around 50ms. This leaves me with ~33ms of latency unaccounted for.

So why does it seem that SwapBuffers() is taking 33ms (2 frames) to finally show on the screen? Is this just how long OpenGL takes? I was under the impression SwapBuffers() would take one frame cycle at most to finish the swap. Are there settings I can look into that would make this faster? I have Vsync turned off in the GPU settings and have set `wglSwapInterval(0)`

Comment: "OpenGL SwapInterval set to false"...so like `wglSwapIntervalEXT(0)`?

Comment: And how much rocket surgery have you done to [DWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager) to disable compositing?

Comment: @genpfault Yes, `wglSwapIntervalEXT(0)` (I have edited the original post for clarity on that). And I have not done anything to DWM. Do you think that could be the problem?